# Can GET, can't DELETE - Azure Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an application that manages `Attachments` associated to a `Post`. I need to `GET` and also `DELETE` them.

The attachments are grouped in Azure Blob Containers (a container per Post).
I try to use the Azure API to delete it, but it says does not found (404).

[image]

but the DELETE does not work

[image]

- The **Access Policy** of the "000001" container is "*Container (read access for containers and blobs)*"
- The **CORS** access allows to DELETE for the presented origin.

Here are another HTTP Headers from localhost:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because a `Delete Blob` request can't be anonymous (a `Get Blob` request can be anonymous depending on the blob container's ACL).

What you would need to do is either create an `Authorization` request header and include that in the request (which is not recommended considering you're making an AJAX call and you would have to expose your account key on the client side for that) or use a `Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL` with `Delete` permission included in the SAS.